# Tramp fails to open remote shell when connecting to android

Tags: tramp, ssh, android, prompt

I'm trying to connect to my Android device via SSH using TRAMP. 
I've setup my SSHDroid, configured ssh keys and my ~/.ssh/config, so I'm able to connect with just `ssh android` from terminal.

But when trying to connect using TRAMP, it hangs with `Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘android’` message. I've configured my `init.el` according with https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Android-shell-setup.html:

```
;; tramp
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
    (list (regexp-quote "android") "remote-shell" "sh"))
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/system/xbin")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "TMPDIR=$HOME")
```

And when changing the `tramp-verbose` to 10, the relevant part from log starts with the message `12:50:05.736545 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell ‘sh’...`, then it seems to enter infinite loop with this fragment:

```
12:50:05.742401 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # tramp/ssh android run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_E
12:50:05.742490 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.742556 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.743037 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # tramp/ssh android run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <
1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_C
12:50:05.743140 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.743196 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.745363 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # tramp/ssh android run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh
```

(it grows longer the longer I wait) and finishes with `12:50:12.025467 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell ‘sh’...failed` after I press `C-g`.

So it looks like it fails to set the environment command and / or recognize the prompt. The weird thing is that it returns the correct prompt `:/storage/emulated/0 $` in the logs. But I have no idea how to make it work.

I'm listing the full debug log below:

```
;; Emacs: 26.1 Tramp: 2.3.3.26.1 -- mode: outline; --
;; Location: /usr/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/net/tramp.elc Git: nil
12:50:05.222514 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # ~ undef
12:50:05.222603 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.222652 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.222696 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.222741 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.222778 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.222927 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for android using ssh...
12:50:05.230222 tramp-get-local-locale (7) # locale en_US.utf8
12:50:05.230335 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-args undef
12:50:05.230385 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-args undef
12:50:05.230450 tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options (4) # Computing ControlMaster options...
12:50:05.230508 tramp-call-process (6) # ‘ssh -o ControlMaster’ nil  temp
12:50:05.232686 tramp-call-process (6) # 255
command-line line 0: missing argument.
12:50:05.232770 tramp-call-process (6) # ‘ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ControlPath=%C 0.0.0.1’ nil  temp
12:50:05.235888 tramp-call-process (6) # 255
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.1 port 22: Invalid argument
12:50:05.235972 tramp-call-process (6) # ‘ssh -o ControlPersist’ nil  temp
12:50:05.237822 tramp-call-process (6) # 255
command-line line 0: Missing ControlPersist argument.
12:50:05.237891 tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options (4) # Computing ControlMaster options...done
12:50:05.237958 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.238006 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.238446 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # vector (tramp-file-name ssh nil nil android nil  nil)
12:50:05.238529 tramp-maybe-open-connection (6) # /bin/sh -i
12:50:05.238577 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # vector (tramp-file-name ssh nil nil android nil  nil)
12:50:05.238626 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.238664 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.240829 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # tramp/ssh android run t
```

## $

12:50:05.240889 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.240930 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.240975 tramp-wait-for-regexp (6) #

## $

12:50:05.241027 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-program undef
12:50:05.241077 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-args undef
12:50:05.241121 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # login-env undef
12:50:05.241166 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # async-args undef
12:50:05.241210 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # connection-timeout undef
12:50:05.241252 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # temp-file undef
12:50:05.241328 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # temp-file /tmp/tramp.HsjOhR
12:50:05.241987 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Sending command ‘exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none android’
12:50:05.242048 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.242094 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-echo nil
12:50:05.242135 tramp-send-command (6) # exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none android
12:50:05.242178 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.242220 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # chunksize nil
12:50:05.242260 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # last-cmd-time (23410 46045 242247 647000)
12:50:05.242303 tramp-send-string (10) # exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none android
12:50:05.242344 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.242401 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # first-password-request 
12:50:05.242676 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
12:50:05.727419 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run t
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:05.727679 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "(.*(user\|login)( .*)?: *)\'" from remote shell
12:50:05.727862 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.728047 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.728330 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "(^.*((?:adgangskode\|contrase(?:(?:ny\|ñ)a)\|geslo\|h(?:(?:asł\|esl)o)\|iphasiwedi\|jelszó\|l(?:ozinka\|ösenord)\|m(?:ot de passe\|ật khẩu)\|pa(?:rola\|s(?:ahitza\|s(?: phrase\|code\|ord\|phrase\|wor[dt])\|vorto))\|s(?:alasana\|enha\|laptažodis)\|wachtwoord\|лозинка\|пароль\|ססמה\|كلمة السر\|गुप्तशब्द\|शब्दकूट\|গুপ্তশব্দ\|পাসওয়ার্ড\|ਪਾਸਵਰਡ\|પાસવર્ડ\|ପ୍ରବେଶ ସଙ୍କେତ\|கடவுச்சொல்\|సంకేతపదము\|ಗುಪ್ತಪದ\|അടയാളവാക്ക്\|රහස්පදය\|ពាក្យសម្ងាត់\|パスワード\|密[码碼]\|암호)).*:\0? *)\'" from remote shell
12:50:05.728540 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.728679 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.728948 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "(^.*(Connection (?:(?:clo\|refu)sed)\|Host key verification failed.\|Login (?:[Ii]ncorrect)\|N(?:ame or service not known\|o supported authentication methods left to try!)\|Permission denied\|(?:Sorry, try again\|Timeout, server not responding).).*\|^.*(Received signal [0-9]+).*)\'" from remote shell
12:50:05.729126 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.729268 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.729469 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "(^[^#$%>
]*[#$%>] *)\'" from remote shell
12:50:05.729622 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.729763 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.729934 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Call ‘tramp-action-succeed’
12:50:05.730113 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.730270 tramp-process-actions (6) # 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:05.730430 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.730848 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
12:50:05.731261 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Found remote shell prompt on ‘android’
12:50:05.731470 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.736420 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-shell sh
12:50:05.736488 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-shell sh
12:50:05.736545 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell ‘sh’...
12:50:05.736660 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.736715 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-echo nil
12:50:05.736761 tramp-send-command (6) # exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' sh 
12:50:05.736810 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:05.736864 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # chunksize nil
12:50:05.736912 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # last-cmd-time (23410 46045 736897 362000)
12:50:05.736966 tramp-send-string (10) # exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' sh 
12:50:05.737015 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:05.737083 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.737134 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.742401 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_E
12:50:05.742490 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.742556 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.743037 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_C
12:50:05.743140 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.743196 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.745363 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
12:50:05.745484 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.745547 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.771143 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run t
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:05.771463 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:05.771628 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:06.773377 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run nil
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:06.773716 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:06.773881 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:07.775587 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run nil
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:07.775882 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:07.776043 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:08.777729 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run nil
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:08.778098 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:08.778262 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:09.780029 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run nil
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:09.780357 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:09.780532 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:10.781488 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run nil
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:10.781781 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:10.781937 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:11.782759 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh android* run nil
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.
ec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.                         <1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra
_EMACS='26.1,tramp:2.3.3.26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tra                         <mp_history PROMPT_COMMAND
26.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND                         <='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3
tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=#\$\  PS2='' PS3                         <='' sh 
:/storage/emulated/0 $ 
12:50:11.783052 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:11.783214 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
12:50:12.025467 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell ‘sh’...failed
12:50:12.025968 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for android using ssh...failed
12:50:12.028822 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # remote-shell sh
12:50:12.029085 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-truename nil
12:50:12.029276 tramp-flush-directory-property (8) # 
12:50:12.029460 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:12.029632 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:12.029805 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # *tramp/ssh android* (vector temp-file last-cmd-time)
12:50:12.029997 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
12:50:12.032534 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # (tramp-file-name ssh nil nil android nil nil nil) (remote-shell process-buffer first-password-request)
12:50:12.032649 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # remote-shell sh
12:50:12.032704 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
12:50:12.032804 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Interrupt received in operation (expand-file-name /ssh:android: /)
12:50:14.521367 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # case-insensitive undef
12:53:46.292938 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # case-insensitive undef
12:54:51.071295 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # case-insensitive undef
12:57:14.209581 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # case-insensitive undef

Comment: I've found one workaround - using adb. After connecting the cable, enabling usb debugging in developer options on my phone and starting the adb-server, I'm able to connect with: `C-x C-f /:adb::/storage/emulated/0`

Comment: I'm happy that `adb` works for you. If you want to get the `ssh` connection working, I recommend that you contact the Tramp mailing list. It is important to add the debug buffer as attachment, because every bit (and non-ascii char) counts. Reading the whole trace buffer here in sx shows only ascii formatted text.